# In Makkos 22a, why are those specific cases given?

Tags: maseches-makos

In Gemarah Makkos 22a, a number of cases are given by different Rabbonim as possible additional averos that can be done while ploughing.  It seems like this could be a far larger list though, especially as some cases appear to not actually be tied to the action of ploughing itself (eg. wearing the Choshen) and some seem quite far fetched.

Some possible other examples: -

- If he kills someone with the plough
- If he is eating pork at the time
- If he is eating on Yom Kippur
- If he is saying lashon hara at the time

etc etc. - the possible list is almost endless, so the question is why were these specific cases chosen?

Answer (score 1):

The Mishnah quoted by the Gemara pretty much asks the question using a different case: someone who wore clothing of *sha'atnez* while plowing. The Mishna says that is not relevant, as the wearing of sha'atnez is not connected to the plowing:

> חנניא בן חכינאי אומר אף הלובש כלאים אמרו לו אינו השם אמר להם אף הנזיר לא הוא השם:
> Ḥananya ben Ḥakhinai says: If he was wearing a garment consisting of diverse kinds of wool and linen while plowing he is also flogged for violating that prohibition. The Sages said to him: That is not a prohibition in the same category as the others, as it is not connected to the act of plowing. Ḥananya ben Ḥakhinai said to them: According to that criterion, the fact that he is a nazirite is also not in the same category, as a nazirite and a priest are not flogged for plowing; rather, they are flogged for contracting impurity imparted by a corpse.

The last three questions you ask are similar. There too there is no connection between the action of plowing and the aveirah being done.

As to the first question, theoretically you could kill someone with a plow. But if he did, the rule of קם ליה בדרבה מיניה would apply. Since the action made the perpetrator liable for the death penalty, he would no longer receive makkos. This would defeat the Mishna's purpose, which is to say the maximum number of times a person could become liable for makkos. This is also the reason the Mishnah says the case is plowing on Yom Tov, not Shabbos. Yom Tov is only a לאו, whereas Shabbos is a חיוב מיתה.

Comment: From what I understood, the Gemarah does finally count that case in the mishna as one of the main list of averos in the main count though?  Also, surely there must be other cases?  eg. if it is someone else's field? If he breaks something belonging to someone else with the plough?  If he destroys hekdesh with the plough?  Are you really saying that these are the only possible ones?